# Undefined index Authorisation in api when sending from ionic

Tags: php, ionic-framework, header, authorization

I am sending my JWT token from local storage to my API in my Authourization header. Everything works on Postman and the user is added to the database. However, in my ionic app I keep getting an error of undefined index.

addPatient

```
token = this.storage.get('token');

addPatient(FirstName, LastName, InjuryDesc, DOB) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer + this.token');
    return this.http.post<any>(apiUrl + 'addPatient.php', 
                                {FirstName, LastName, InjuryDesc, DOB}, 
                                {headers});
}
```

php api

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$jwt = $headers['Authorization'];


$response['jwt']= $jwt;
```

Comment: Need to check if it is set, however I can't tell why it wouldn't be set.  But I don't think this does what you want `'Bearer + this.token'`.

Comment: Its is really not clear whats what here, but you PHP script does not appear to be sending anything out in response to be ing called

Comment: Try:    'Bearer ' + this.token

Comment: Still isnt working. Its saying the problem is within the API (Undefined index Authorization) yet it is working on postman?